# Hibernate SessionFactory creation failure when running JUnit tests only

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, junit

I'm using Eclipse and Hibernate to develope a J2EE web app.
When running/debugging the web app, my hibernate-related code works just fine.
But if I run a junit test that tests some of my hibernate-related code, I get an "Initial SessionFactory creation failed" error.

The specific error message is as follows:
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.(Lorg/hibernate/mapping/Collection;Lorg/hibernate/cache/access/CollectionRegionAccessStrategy;Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;Lorg/hibernate/engine/SessionFactoryImplementor;)V

Any comments or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be good to show how you're initializing the sessionFactory for your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running your unit tests against a different version of the Hibernate library than you are compiling it against.

Comment: I think you're right.  I will check the classpath more carefully.